# Cannot find ETW event ID/Name

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-on-premises

I have created a Service Fabric Application from the visual studio wizard

This is mostly working, but the diagnostic events viewer is not working

This requires either an ETW Provider name or GUID

How do I find this?

I have tried the one shown in debug Arguments in the service fabric tools output and that doesnt work

I am running this as a development cluster at the moment

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Found it but I am going to keep this question in case other people have the same problem

I did a search for EventSource and found

```
[EventSource(Name = "NAME IS HERE")]
```

In the ServiceEventSource.cs file

Using this works!

Paul

Comment: Note that the Service Fabric tooling for Visual Studio (2017, I don't know about 2015) is supposed to harvest these attributes from your project and populate the list automatically so you shouldn't have to do this. But there is a bug that breaks this process. The only way I've found to fix it is to uninstall VS2017, and the SF SDK & runtime, and then reinstall everything. I also uninstalled all the various Azure components for good measure. I spent my morning doing this *grumble*.  Well at least I don't have to paste the ETW provider names in by hand with each run now. :)

Comment: Update: it was ReSharper. As soon as I installed it, auto-harvesting of Event Sources broke. Then I uninstalled Resharper again, and it's fixed.

Comment: Update2: Seems it's a known issue, in the Service Fabric tooling code: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466683